# PHP Dice IoC - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dice, php-5.5

I am trying to use [Dice](https://r.je/dice.html) for my dependency injection.

When I run the code below (from Dice doc),

```
include 'dice.php';

class A {
    private $b;

    public function __construct(B $b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

class B {
    private $c,$d;

    public function __construct(C $c, D $d) {
        $this->c = $c;
        $this->d = $d;
    }
}

class C {

}

class D {
    private $e;

    public function __construct(E $e) {
        $this->e = $e;
    }
}

class E {

}


$dice = new \Dice\Dice;
$a = $dice->create('A');
print_r($a);
```

I get this error,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:...\dice.php on line
>   38

If you open [dice.php](https://github.com/TomBZombie/Dice/blob/master/dice.php), this is the line the error message refers to,

```
else $object = $params ? new $class->name(...$params($args)) : new $class->name;
```

I does look strange to me - `...$params` what is that??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vararg/splat operator (`...`) is a new feature introduced in PHP 5.6. Strange that a popular library relies on such obscure syntax but it seems you have to upgrade for your code to successfully run.

[PHP 5.6 New features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

[PHP 5.6 and the Splat Operator](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator)

Comment: @tealou If you look on the Dice website (https://github.com/TomBZombie/Dice), you can see that there's a PHP 5.4-5.5 version still available. You seem to be running a very recent version that specifically takes advantage of PHP 5.6 features.

Comment: silkfire, thanks for pointing that out. I would love to use php5.6. But I'm afraid most commercial/ shared server are still on 5.5....

Comment: @tealou 5.6 is still very new and I think it would take awhile for major shared hostings to catch on. Here's the Dice version (branch) you require: https://github.com/TomBZombie/Dice/tree/PHP5.4---PHP5.5

Comment: yes it is going to take a while... thanks for the link. Just tested it and works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4-5.5 version isn't available anymore on https://github.com/TomBZombie/Dice. Most of shared hosting still use 5.5. Can anybody set up to be accessible from sdome link.
I know it's a little violation of rules. Thank You!